# Derivation of M-step in EM algorithm for mixture of Gaussians

Tags: expectation-maximization, gaussian-mixture-distribution

I am trying to derive the parameter estimation equations for the [M-step](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expectation%E2%80%93maximization_algorithm#M_step) of the expectation maximization (EM) [algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expectation%E2%80%93maximization_algorithm) for a mixture Gaussians when all Gaussians share the same covariance matrix $\mathbf{\Sigma}$.

*[Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning](http://users.isr.ist.utl.pt/%7Ewurmd/Livros/school/Bishop%20-%20Pattern%20Recognition%20And%20Machine%20Learning%20-%20Springer%20%202006.pdf)* by Bishop has a section on EM for Gaussian mixtures, and it includes a derivation of the M-step when all $K$ Gaussians have different covariance matrices $\mathbf{\Sigma_k}$. I think that if I can understand this derivation well, I can modify it to get what I want.

I understand the derivation given by Bishop for the M-step equation for $\mathbf{\mu_k}$. However, the book does not show detailed steps for the derivation of the M-step for $\mathbf{\Sigma_k}$. When I tried to derive it myself by computing  $\frac{\partial \mathbf{L}}{\partial \mathbf{\Sigma_k}}$ and setting it to 0, I came across the following derivative that I don't know how to deal with:

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{\Sigma_k}} \left ( (2\pi)^{-d/2}|\mathbf{\Sigma_k}|^{-1/2}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(x-\mathbf{\mu_k})^T\mathbf{\Sigma_k}^{-1}(x-\mathbf{\mu_k})}\right )
$$

Basically, it's the derivative of the multivariate Gaussian pdf with respect to the covariance matrix. How do I compute this derivative? I've computed the derivative of the *logarithm* of this function before when studying Gaussian Bayes classifiers, so that makes me think I've made a mistake somewhere.

Answer (score 4):

I've found the answer and I'm posting it for posterity. I mentioned in the question that computing the derivative of the *logarithm* of the PDF was easier. It turns out that this can be used to compute the derivative of the PDF itself:

$$
\frac{\partial \ln (f)}{\partial \mathbf{\Sigma}_k} = \frac{1}{f} \frac{\partial f}{\partial \mathbf{\Sigma}_k}\\
\Rightarrow \frac{\partial f}{\partial \mathbf{\Sigma}_k} = f \cdot\frac{\partial \ln (f)}{\partial \mathbf{\Sigma}_k}
$$

Also, it turns out that taking the derivative of the PDF with respect to $\mathbf{\Sigma}^{-1}$ is easier and leads to the same answer.