# Derivation of M step for Gaussian mixture model

Tags: mathematical-statistics, clustering, gaussian-mixture-distribution, expectation-maximization, calculus

### Summary

So to summarize my question, how can I take
\begin{align}
= \sum_{i=1}^{n}W_{i1} \left(log (1-\sum_{j=2}^{K}\pi_j)  -\frac{1}{2} log(|\Sigma_1|) -\frac{d}{2} log(2\pi) -\frac{1}{2}(x_i-\mu_1)^{T} \Sigma_{1}^{-1}(x_i-\mu_1) \right)+ 
     \sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=2}^{K} W_{ij} \left( log(\pi_j) -\frac{1}{2} log (|\Sigma_j|) -\frac{d}{2} log(2\pi) -\frac{1}{2}(x_i-\mu_j)^{T} \Sigma_{j}^{-1}(x_i-\mu_j)\right)
\end{align}
and maximize it with regards to $\mu_{j}$ and $\Sigma_{j}$. I am having issues with the calculus. Below I provide a long derivation of the E step and how I got to this point. This is not necessary for you to read in order to answer my question.

## EM algorithm background

The [expectation maximisation algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expectation%E2%80%93maximization_algorithm) can be defined as an alternating (iterative) algorithm, where we start with an initial value for $\theta$ as we would in a gradient descent approach. In gradient descent we would move in the direction of the gradient many times in order to maximise the function. However, in this case we cannot do a gradient descent since $l(\theta|x,z)$ and therefore have to do an alternating expectation maximisation:

1. set $\theta_0$
2. Alternate between:

\begin{align*}
  &  E :\text{To find an expression for} &\\
  &  E_z\left[l(\theta|X,Z)|X,\theta\right] &\\
  &  = \sum_{all Z} l(\theta|x,z) P(Z=z|x,\theta)
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
    & M :\text{Maximise over $\theta$} &\\
    & E_z \left[l (\theta|X,Z)| X,\theta \right] &\\
\end{align*}

We want to maximise the log-likelihood: 
$l(\theta|x)$

Problem: Difficult to maximise it directly.

\begin{align*}
    \theta & = \left\{\pi_1,\dots,\pi_k,\mu_1,\dots,\mu_k,\Sigma_1,\dots,\Sigma_k \right\} & \\
    l(\theta|x) & = \sum_{i=1}^{n} log \left(\sum_{k=1}^{K} \pi_k \frac{1}{|\Sigma_k|^{1/2}} \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{d/2}} \operatorname{exp}\left(-\frac{1}{2}(x_i-\mu_i)\Sigma_{k}^{-1} (x_i-\mu_k)\right)\right) &\\
\end{align*}

Difficult to maximise $l(\theta|x)$ because we have $n$ sum inside a log so we are trying to perform an EM procedure, so we end up with $n$ sum outside a log. 
Let $Z$ be a vector of length $n$, with $Z_i$ being the identity of the component which generated $x_i$. Then,

\begin{align*}
     l(\theta|X,Z) & = \sum_{i=1}^{n} log \left(\pi_{Z_i} \frac{1}{|\Sigma_{Z_i}|^{1/2}} \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{d/2}} \operatorname{exp}\left(-\frac{1}{2}(x_i-\mu_{Z_i})\Sigma_{Z_i}^{-1} (x_i-\mu_{Z_i})\right)\right)
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
    P(Z_i=j|X,\theta) & = \frac{P\left(X=x_i|\theta, Z_i =j \right) P\left(Z_i=j|\theta\right)}{\sum_{k=1}^{K}P\left(X=x_i|\theta, Z_i=k \right)P\left(Z_i=k|\theta\right)} &\\
                      & = \frac{\frac{1}{|\Sigma_j|^{1/2}} \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{d/2}} \operatorname{exp} \left(-\frac{1}{2}(x_i-\mu_j)^T\Sigma_{j}^{-1}(x_i-\mu_j)\right)\pi_j}{\sum_{k=1}^{K}\pi_k \frac{1}{|\Sigma_k|^{1/2}(2\pi)^{d/2}} \operatorname{exp} \left(-\frac{1}{2}(x_i-\mu_k)^{T}\Sigma_{k}^{-1}(x_i-\mu_j)\right)} &\\
                      & = w_{ij} &\\
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
    & E: E_Z \left[l(\theta | X_i, Z) |X,\theta \right] &\\
    & E_Z \left[\sum_{i=1}^{n} log \left(\pi_{Z_i} \frac{1}{|\Sigma_{Z_i}|^{1/2} (2\pi)^{d/2}} \operatorname{exp}\left(-\frac{1}{2}(x_i-\mu_{Z_i})^T\Sigma_{Z_i}^{-1}(x_i-\mu_{Z_i})\right)\right)|X,\theta\right] &\\
    & = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^{K} P\left(Z_i=j|X,\theta\right) log \left(\pi_j \frac{1}{|\Sigma_j|^{1/2}(2\pi)^{d/2}} \operatorname{exp}\left(-\frac{1}{2}(x_i-\mu_i)^{T}\Sigma_j^{-1}(x_i-\mu_i)\right)|X,\theta\right) &\\
    & = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^{K} W_{ij} \left(log (\pi_j) -\frac{1}{2} log (|\Sigma_j|) -\frac{d}{2} log (2\pi) \left(-\frac{1}{2}(x_i-\mu_i)^{T}\Sigma_j^{-1}(x_i-\mu_i)\right)\right) &\\
    & \text{set $\pi_1=1-\sum_{j=2}^{K}\pi_j$} &\\
    & = \sum_{i=1}^{n}W_{i1} \left(log (1-\sum_{j=2}^{K}\pi_j) \right) -\frac{1}{2} log(|\Sigma_j|) -\frac{d}{2} log(2\pi) -\frac{1}{2}(x_i-\mu_j)^{T} \Sigma_{j}^{-1}(x_i-\mu_j) + &\\
    & \sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=2}^{K} W_{ij} (log(\pi_j)) -\frac{1}{2} log (|\Sigma_j|) -\frac{d}{2} log(2\pi) -\frac{1}{2}(x_i-\mu_j)^{T} \Sigma_{j}^{-1}(x_i-\mu_j) &
\end{align*}

for $j=2,3,\dots,K$.

My question is how do I maximize the last part above with respect to $\mu_{j}$ and $\Sigma_{j}$.

\begin{align*}
    & M :\text{Maximise over $\theta$} &\\
    & E_z \left[l (\theta|X,Z)| X,\theta \right] &\\
\end{align*}

### Summary

So to summarize my question, how can I take
\begin{align}
= \sum_{i=1}^{n}W_{i1} \left(log (1-\sum_{j=2}^{K}\pi_j)  -\frac{1}{2} log(|\Sigma_1|) -\frac{d}{2} log(2\pi) -\frac{1}{2}(x_i-\mu_1)^{T} \Sigma_{1}^{-1}(x_i-\mu_1) \right)+ 
     \sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=2}^{K} W_{ij} \left( log(\pi_j) -\frac{1}{2} log (|\Sigma_j|) -\frac{d}{2} log(2\pi) -\frac{1}{2}(x_i-\mu_j)^{T} \Sigma_{j}^{-1}(x_i-\mu_j)\right)
\end{align}
and maximize it with regards to $\mu$ and $\Sigma$

I have found a [similar post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/243128/derivation-of-m-step-in-em-algorithm-for-mixture-of-gaussians), but it was only with regards to differentiating  $\Sigma_k$ .

Comment: From what I understand the M step is maximizing your E step.

Comment: Take the derivative of the $M$ function with respect to each unknown parameter, set to zero, solve.

Comment: Or check [this video](https://youtu.be/zL_MHtT56S0).

Comment: Thanks @Xi'an I have been trying, but my math background isn't that great. Therefore the bounty that I am awarding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR, we have that

$$\mu^*_k = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n W_{ik}x_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n W_{ik}}$$
$$\Sigma^*_k = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} W_{ik}(x_i -\mu^*_k)(x_i - \mu^*_k)'}{\sum_{i=1}^n W_{ik}}$$

In particular, this is the same as finding the MLE of a gaussian rv, but we weight by $W_{ik}$ for each $k$.

See below for the derivation, which is fairly similar to MLE for multivariate gaussian.

It may help to approach the E step a bit differently. In your second equation for the E step, you correctly have that you want to maximize

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^{K} P\left(Z_i=j|X,\theta\right) log \left(\pi_j \frac{1}{|\Sigma_j|^{1/2}(2\pi)^{d/2}} \operatorname{exp}\left(-\frac{1}{2}(x_i-\mu_i)^{T}\Sigma_j^{-1}(x_i-\mu_i)\right)|X,\theta\right)$$

but we can more simply write that as

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^{K} P\left(Z_i=j|X,\theta\right)\left(log(\pi_j) +  log\left(\mathcal{N}(x_i;\mu_j,\Sigma_j)\right)\right)$$

where $\mathcal{N}$ denotes the gaussian density. Following your notation, let $W_{ij} = P\left(Z_i=j|X,\theta\right)$. As pointed out in the comments, we want to basically take derivatives with respect to $\mu_k$ and $\Sigma_k$ for each $k=1,\dots,K$, set to $0$, and solve to find the maximum. Our first step is to note that for a given $k$, taking derivative with respect to either $k$ parameter will be zero for any $j\neq k$ in that summation, and so for any $(i,j)$ where $j\neq k$, the derivative will just be zero. So maximizing the above is the same as maximizing

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} W_{ik}\left(log(\pi_k) +  log\left(\mathcal{N}(x_i;\mu_k,\Sigma_k)\right)\right)$$

A key point of the EM algorithm is precisely that $W_{ik}$ is estimated in the E step, and so we can think of it as a constant for our cases, and while we're at it, since
$$W_{ik}\left(log(\pi_k) +  log\left(\mathcal{N}(x_i;\mu_k,\Sigma_k)\right)\right) = W_{ik}log(\pi_k) +  W_{ik}log\left(\mathcal{N}(x_i;\mu_k,\Sigma_k)\right)$$

for any $i$, we can also ignore that first part as taking derivative with respect to either parameter will be zero. So maximizing the E step for the $k$-th parameters is the same as maximizing

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} W_{ik} log\left(\mathcal{N}(x_i;\mu_k,\Sigma_k)\right)$$

Suppose that $\Sigma_k \in \mathbb{R}^{d\times d}$. Then we know that the PDF of the guassian normal is
$$\frac{1}{2\pi^{d/2}\det(\Sigma_k)^{-1/2}} \exp(-\frac{1}{2}(x_i-\mu_k)'\Sigma_k^{-1}(x-\mu_k))$$

and taking log and using all the properties of log (in particular, $log(xz/y) = log(x) + log(z) - log(y)$ and $log(e(x)) = x)$), we have

$$log\left(\mathcal{N}(x_i;\mu_k,\Sigma_k)\right) = log(1) - log(2pi^{-d/2}) - \frac{1}{2}log(\det(\Sigma_k)) - \frac{1}{2}(x_i-\mu_k)'\Sigma_k^{-1}(x_i-\mu_k)$$

and again, since we are taking derivative, all the parts that don't include $\mu_k$ or $\Sigma_k$ will be set to zero, so maximizing

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} W_{ik} log\left(\mathcal{N}(x_i;\mu_k,\Sigma_k)\right)$$

is the same as maximizing

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} W_{ik}\left(-\frac{1}{2}log(\det(\Sigma_k)) - \frac{1}{2}(x_i-\mu_k)'\Sigma_k^{-1}(x_i-\mu_k)\right)$$

which simplifies to

$$-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{n} W_{ik}log(\det(\Sigma_k)) - \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{n} W_{ik}(x_i-\mu_k)'\Sigma_k^{-1}(x_i-\mu_k)$$

Okay, we are finally ready to take derivatives, but we will need to know some vector and matrix derivative properties, so let's draw from the lovely [Matrix Cookbook](http://www2.imm.dtu.dk/pubdb/edoc/imm3274.pdf). From it, we know that $\frac{\partial x'Ax}{\partial x} = 2Ax$ if $x$ does not depend on $A$ and $A$ is symmetric. Since $\Sigma_k^{-1}$ is positive semidefinite, it is symmetric. So taking derivative with respect to $\mu_k$, we get rid of the first part, and for the second part we basically chain rule by taking with respect to $(x_i-\mu_k)$ and our derivative rule and then taking derivative of that with $\mu_k) and get that

$$\frac{\partial \frac{-1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{n} W_{ik}(x_i-\mu_k)'\Sigma_k^{-1}(x_i-\mu_k)}{\partial \mu_k} = \sum_{i=1}^n W_{ik}\Sigma_k^{-1}(\mu_k - x_i) = 0 $$

which implies that

$$\sum_{i=1}^n W_{ik}\Sigma_k^{-1}\mu_k =  \sum_{i=1}^n W_{ik}\Sigma_k^{-1}x_i \implies \mu_k\sum_{i=1}^n W_{ik} = \sum_{i=1}^n W_{ik}x_i$$

and so $\mu_k = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n W_{ik}x_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n W_{ik}}$. Yay!

Now let's do $\Sigma_k$. This one is trickier, but the key facts you need to know are that $\frac{\partial{x'Ax}}{\partial A} = xx'$, and that $\frac{\partial log(\det(A))}{\partial A} = A^{-T}$. Again check out the Matrix Cookbook to see why. We will also use the fact that
$$-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{n} W_{ik}log(\det(\Sigma_k)) = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{n} W_{ik}log(\det(\Sigma_k^{-1}))$$

which follows from pushing the $-1$ into the log and using the fact that $det(A^{-1}) = det(A)^{-1}$. Then we can re-write

$$-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{n} W_{ik}log(\det(\Sigma_k)) - \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{n} W_{ik}(x_i-\mu_k)'\Sigma_k^{-1}(x_i-\mu_k) = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{n} W_{ik}log(\det(\Sigma_k^{-1})) - \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{n} W_{ik}(x_i-\mu_k)'\Sigma_k^{-1}(x_i-\mu_k)$$

Taking derivative with respect to $\Sigma_k^{-1}$, we have

$$\frac{\partial \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{n} W_{ik}log(\det(\Sigma_k^{-1})) - \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{n} W_{ik}(x_i-\mu_k)'\Sigma_k^{-1}(x_i-\mu_k)}{\partial \Sigma_k^{-1}} = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^n W_{ik}\Sigma_k - \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{n} W_{ik}(x_i -\mu_k)(x_i - \mu_k)'$$

And setting this to zero and solving for $\Sigma_k$ gives us that

$$0 = \sum_{i=1}^n W_{ik}\Sigma_k -\sum_{i=1}^{n} W_{ik}(x_i -\mu_k)(x_i - \mu_k)'$$

which simplifies to

$$\Sigma_k = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} W_{ik}(x_i -\mu_k)(x_i - \mu_k)'}{\sum_{i=1}^n W_{ik}}$$

using the previously maximized $\mu_k$ here, and we are done!

Comment: fixed some typos... in particular it should have been $W_{ik}$ throughout, not $W_{ij}$.